# Will this track correctly?

Tags: javascript

I have two questions regarding ads:

1. If I use `window.open`, is that considered a pop-up by pop-up blockers? What about regular `<a href="">` with target?
2. If I have a JavaScript method that runs on click, will that method still run if the user <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clicks on the link (ie. open in new window)?

Thanks!

Comment: On point (2), note that the click event applies to left (or primary button) clicks, so while ctrl-click is still a left click you can also open links in other tabs with a middle-click or right-click plus context menu option.

Answer (score 1):

1. For me in Google Chrome, window.open is stopped by the pop-up blocker unless it is triggered by an onclick or similar event (e.g. onmouseup, onmousedown). Links opening in a new window will never be considered popups.
2. Yes, any type of click works, even clicks to open in a new window. (But not clicks that open a context menu, such as right click or ctrl+click on macs)

Comment: That's how it works for me too... i guess it only blocks window.open when it happens without user action. Still I don't want to risk it.

Answer (score 1):

> If I use `window.open`, is that considered a pop-up by pop-up blockers? What about regular `<a href="">` with target?

Both of these will normally be considered popups; however, the former is usually automatically blocked by browsers (at least in current browsers—IE 9, Firefox 8, Chrome 14, etc.), while the latter is usually allowed by browsers (but usually blocked by popup blockers).

> If I have a JavaScript method that runs on click, will that method still run if the user <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clicks on the link (ie. open in new window)?

Yes, it is still considered a click.

Comment: I understand, I guess the safest way is to use same page links (href with no target)

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a pop-up and it will normally not be blocked.

Your later question is easier to solve. Try to upvote this answer while holding control, you won't.

Comment: Ctrl+upvote works for me in Google Chrome. Also, a pop-up blocker will consider both of those as popups: your first sentence is ambiguous.

Comment: Actually, I can still upvote this answer using the open in new tab/window button.

Comment: I can upvote while holding control aswell... I guess it depends on browser. So for ads just to be safe i should use regular href

Comment: If you were that confident why didn't you ask us to _downvote_ your answer?

Comment: It is considered a pop-up AND will _normally_, in the sense of you not abusing it for ads or making it annoying, not be blocked.